# How to retrieve all choice field values using ecmascript – SharePoint 2010 and bind to html dropdown in the content editor webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-editor-web-part

I need to bind the SharePoint 2010 choice column in the HTML dropdown of the content editor webpart..

I have followed [this blog](http://haseebakhtar.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/how-to-retrieve-all-choice-field-values-using-ecmascript-sharepoint-2010/) but it could not achieve my requirement.

I have replace my listname, columnname and select id of dropdown.

I have put below code in the text file and give the path in the contentEditor webpart. Please check the code below and let me know what wrong i have done.

Code snippet:

```
<select id="input2" style="width:30%"><option>Any</option></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = retrieveListItems;
    var deptChoiceField;

    function retrieveListItems() {
        varclientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var webSite = clientContext.get_web();
        var lists = webSite.get_lists();
        var oList = lists.getByTitle('as');
        deptChoiceField = clientContext.castTo(oList.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle('Engineer'), SP.FieldChoice);
        clientContext.load(deptChoiceField);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.fillDropDown), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListDataLoadQueryFailed));
    }

    function onListDataLoadQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert(‘Request failed.‘ + args.get_message() + ‘\n’ + args.get_stackTrace());
    }

    function fillDropDown() {
        var choices = deptChoiceField.get_choices();
        var ddlCategory = document.getElementById(‘input2‘);
        if (ddlCategory != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
                var theOption = new Option;
                theOption.text = choices[i];
                ddlCategory.options[i] = theOption;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My List name is 'as'. My choice field column name is 'Engineer'. and dropdown id is 'input2'

Comment: Please post and format your code. This always helps to see where you might have made a mistake.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Is `fillDropDown` actually getting invoked?

Answer (score 1):

One very easy way to do this is using the `ListData.svc`.

Imagine your list is called *IssueTracker* and your field is called *Products*. Using the library of your choice, I am using DataJS (from Microsoft) in this example but you could just as easily use jQuery or Kendo UI's DataSource.

```
OData.read(
    "../_vti_bin/ListData.svc/IssueTrackerProducts",
    function (data, response) {
        list.taskList.hasReturned = true;
        onSuccessMethod(data, response);
    },
    function (error) {
        list.taskList.hasReturned = true;
        onFailureMethod(error);
    }
);

{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "uri": "http://sp-server.domain.com/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/IssueTrackerProduct('Aftermarket%20Hardware')",
                    "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.IssueTrackerProductValue"
                },
                "Value": "Aftermarket Hardware"
            },
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "uri": "http://sp-server.domain.com/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/IssueTrackerProduct('Aftermarket%20Software')",
                    "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.IssueTrackerProductValue"
                },
                "Value": "Aftermarket Software"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As far as the JS CSOM goes the code on that blog is incomplete in one of the lines. Here is a snippet I have put together for you that I have tested:

```
var field,
    fieldChoices;
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('IssueTracker');
field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle('Product');
var choiceField = ctx.castTo(field, SP.FieldChoice);
ctx.load(field);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
          fieldChoices = choiceField.get_choices();
          //FieldChoices is now an array with the possible values for
          //that field
},
function(sender, args){console.log("Handle error");});
```

**Edit:** The code you added seems right. Here is an example that is a little different from yours as it takes into account IE7 as well.http://jsbin.com/iyojir/1/edit

Comment: I got the JS CSOM code above from this page a while ago and have been using it since then: http://blogs.technet.com/b/pfemike/archive/2012/07/12/getting-all-values-from-a-choice-field-in-sharepoint-2010-using-csom.aspx

Comment: Hi Robert, How to use data.js(odata.read) in the ContentEditor webpart? I am new to using odata.

Comment: Have you tried the code in my second example? That is just the SharePoint ECMA Client Object Model. It might be easier just to use it.

Comment: S.. I have tried... I could not able to get the output. I have copy the code and add it in the txt file and uploaded in the shared document and the url given in the Content editor webpart. Note: Above i have attached my code.. Can you check and tell where i went wrong when i give as txt file...Please help..

Comment: Are you saying you saved it as a `.txt` file in a shared documents library and not as a `.js` file?

Comment: S.. I have saved as .txt file....